# Flutter Cannot show List item in Drawar

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter.
I am trying to create list view dynamically using server response JSON data using futureBuilder. The code writen by me while wathing YouTube videos, but I can't understand what is the mistake.

//It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.//

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home.dart';
void main() {
    runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: home(),
    ));

}
```

home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class home extends StatefulWidget {
home({Key key}):super();
  @override
  homepage createState() =>new homepage();

}
class homepage extends State<home>{
  Color theme = Colors.lightBlue;
  Color theme_text = Colors.white;


  Future<List<category>> _getCategory() async {
    var data = await http
        .get("https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/VJ6EHYFO_");
    debugPrint(data.body);
    var jsondata = json.decode(data.body);
    List<category> list = [];
    for (var u in jsondata) {
      category c = category(u['name'], u['id']);
      list.add(c);
    }

    return list;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: theme,
        title: Text('SIMS Home Page'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            onPressed: () => debugPrint("search pressed"),
          )
        ],
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text(
                "Not Signed",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(color: theme_text, fontSize: 20),
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: theme,
              ),
            ),
            FutureBuilder(
              future: _getCategory(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("Loading..."),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return ListTile(title: Text(snapshot.data[index]),);
                      });
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }




class category {
  final name;
  final id;

  category(this.name, this.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use shrinkwrap property of listView.builder to get it work. it will allow listview to grow only that much which is require.

Moreover, in text view you are assigning items directly you have to access name and id individually as shown in below code.

```
Container(
          height: 150,
          child: DrawerHeader(
            child: Text(
              "Not Signed",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(color: theme_text, fontSize: 20),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: theme,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        FutureBuilder(
          future: _getCategory(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Loading..."),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 150,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true, //added line
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(snapshot.data[index]
                            .toString()), //accessing name from json
                      );
                    }),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Your Welcome! Happy Coding!

Comment: But I get one more problem, the list view cannot scrollable

Comment: did you try to add more items ?

Comment: added NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() but it scroll whol drawer(with header)

Comment: if you provide height to listview then it will work as expected, so you have to fix hight of header and accordingly listview's as well. i changed my answer. @sanjaybhatt

Comment: Glad to heat that. Accept my answer, so other community member can also take benefit.